# Get all the words with spelling errors that match a column in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of keywords in a Python data frame (df1) and there is another data frame that has column with string of words from user input (df2). The goal of the program is to iterate each word in the Keyword column and check if the words from the user input exist in the keyword and create another column in df2 with the matches. Misspelled words should get matched too. For example, I have used animals here, but it is something else in our database, and the keywords can be up to 500.

```
 df2:
  Verbatim      
dog, Caat      
Orange         
Monky , lion   
C              
Human          
Tiger & new Monkey

df1:
 Keywords   
Dog         
Cat         
Monkey      
Lion        
Tiger       
Zebra       
Rabbit      

keywords = df1['Keywords'].to_list()

from difflib import get_close_matches
for i in df2['Verbatim']:
    print((get_close_matches(i, keywords))
```

When I run the above code, it does matches some but not all correctly, I am not sure what is wrong. Also when I try to do the following assignment:

```
df_new['match'] = get_close_matches(i, keywords)
```

I get the error, length of values does not match length of index. The output I am looking for is:

```
 df2:
  Verbatim_new      
dog, Cat      
Nan         
Monkey , lion   
Nan              
Nan          
Tiger, Monkey
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So to address two different thigs.

First, "it does matches some but not all correctly" isn't enough context for us to help much. If you could give some example inputs and their relevant outputs that could give us more context. I've never worked with difflib but I would assume there are some parameters you can adjust that might improve your results?

Secondly, in regards to the pandas part of your question, when you do df['column_name'] pandas expects you to provide enough results to fill the column (so if your dataframe has 100 rows it would expect 100 data points to be returned from your function). For what you're doing you want to do something like the below:

```
df['match'] = df['Verbatim'].apply(lambda x: get_close_matches(x))
```

What this does is apply the function on each row in the column Verbatim.

If you wanted to stick with your for loop (which Pandas discourages. A very clear reason is performance), you would do the following:

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    df2.at[index, 'match'] = get_close_matches(row['Verbatim'], keywords))
```

Comment: Your point about using loop helped me figured out solution to the problem, it is working as I expected it should, though it is not perfect, it is going in the right direction

Comment: Just a comment about loop with pandas: they're probably the slowest thing you can do with pandas. I just realised I miss the keywords variable in the .apply() version I provided. If you can get that working I think it would be the optimal solution